# Grand Central Dispatch-Check for Task Completion

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I want to do a lengthy background operation;after completion I need to refresh a TableView

```
let globalQueue = DispatchQueue.global()
                globalQueue.async {
                   //My lengthy code 
                }
```

I need to do this after the Async Task Completes

```
 treeview.reloadData()
```

How can I hook to GCD Task completion Event? I have C# Background, I'am new to SWIFT.. Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to place it in a `main` queue after your code:

```
let globalQueue = DispatchQueue.global()
globalQueue.async {
    // Your code here
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.treeview.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah,treeview is in my UI.

Comment: Actually I needed to explicitly define self i.e: `self.treeview.reloadData();`

Comment: will accept it as an answer .. need to wait 6 mins more.BTW is there a loading animation panel in SWIFT (OSX) by default.

Comment: @techno you can look at [`NSProgressIndicator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsprogressindicator)

Comment: got it... `@IBOutlet weak var spinner: NSProgressIndicator! spinner.startAnimation(self)` As you can see I need to pass the sender object argument explicitly ,so I passed `self` as the sender.. hope I'm correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `DispatchGroup`. With a group you can create dependencies and be notified when everything has completed.

```
// create a group to synchronize our tasks
let group = DispatchGroup()

// The 'enter' method increments the group's task count…
group.enter()
let globalQueue = DispatchQueue.global()
globalQueue.async {
    // my lengthy code 
     group.leave()
}

// closure will be called when the group's task count reaches 0
group.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Totally get it man. This is more useful for doing multiple tasks on separate threads and waiting for all of them.

Comment: Seems like I cannot use GCD as I need to cancel the Async task when user clicks on a Button.Can you please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904176/dismissing-view-controller-not-stopping-async-task/