# Dismissing View Controller not stopping Async Task

Tags: swift, macos, swift3

I'm using the following code to do some complex background operations from a newly launched view controller

```
 let globalQueue = DispatchQueue.global()
  globalQueue.async {
   //complex job 
  }
```

When the user clicks on the cancel button, I call

```
self.dismissViewController(self)
```

But it seems this does not stop the background task.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If it will be in `DispatchQueue.global()` it stop after compeletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API that can cancel running thread. Instead, can add cancellation flag to check in handling response.

```
var dispatchItem:DispatchWorkItem!

      func executeDispatch()   {

        dispatchItem = DispatchWorkItem {
          for i in 1...200 {
            sleep(1)
            if !(self.dispatchItem.isCancelled)  {
               print("item \(i)")
            }else {
              print("cancel")
          }
        }

        DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: dispatchItem)
      }


      func stop(_ sender: Any) {

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
          self.dispatchItem.cancel()
        }
      }
```

Comment: Well this would not prevent the for loop from being executed 200 times.

Answer (score 1):

**Create the dispatch work item.**

```
//create the dispatch work item
var disptachWorkItem:DispatchWorkItem?
```

**Now put the complex task in dispatch work item.**

```
dispatchWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem {
//Some complex job
}
```

**Execute the Work on default global queue.**

```
DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: dispatchWorkItem!)
```

**You can find out when the viewController is being dismissed.**

```
DispatchQueue.global.async {
dispatchWorkItem?.cancel()
}
presentingViewController?.dismissViewController(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... where should I create the dispatch work item?

Comment: Wherever you want to execute the complex job, first create DispatchWorkItem and execute it rather than directly putting in global queue.

Comment: Thanks.. but how I can hook onto the Dimiss event of the View Controller?

Comment: And the should I declare DispatchWorkItem as a global variable? I cannot get the reference to it.. on button click.

Comment: Make it the  private property of the view controller so you can access it anywhere in that view controller.